# Exporting java output to text

Tags: java

First time using a java community but I don't understand how to format the code to come out properly here. The tutorials to export my output to notepad text format is confusing to me. I uploaded my code in a text file for you all to see.

The code is basically used to compare a true or false class questions array

```
package grades;

import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Grades {

    String[] studentIDArr = new String[8];
    String score = "";
    String answer1 = "";
    String answer2 = "";
    String answer3 = "";
    String answer4 = "";
    String answer5 = "";
    String answer6 = "";
    String answer7 = "";
    String answer8 = "";
    String answer9 = "";
    String answer10 = "";
    int AnswerKey = 0;
    String answerKey1 = "";
    String answerKey2 = "";
    String answerKey3 = "";
    String answerKey4 = "";
    String answerKey5 = "";
    String answerKey6 = "";
    String answerKey7 = "";
    String answerKey8 = "";
    String answerKey9 = "";
    String answerKey10 = "";
    String Opt = "*****Enter T or F*****";
    int pass = 0;
    int fail = 0;
    int passcounter = 0;
    int failcounter = 0;
    JOptionPane popup = new JOptionPane();
    static int i = 0;

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO code application logic here

        //invoke the constructor method
        new Grades();

    }

    public Grades() {
        AnswerKey = Integer.parseInt(popup.showInputDialog("Please enter Answer Key Number"));
        if (AnswerKey == 0000) {
            answerKey1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Opt);
            answerKey2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Opt);
            answerKey3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Opt);
            answerKey4 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Opt);
            answerKey5 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Opt);
            answerKey6 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Opt);
            answerKey7 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Opt);
            answerKey8 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Opt);
            answerKey9 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Opt);
            answerKey10 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Opt);
            for (i = 0; i < studentIDArr.length; i++) {
                studentIDArr[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter Student ID");
                studentIDArr[i] = studentIDArr[i].replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
                answer1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Opt);
                if (answer1.equals(answerKey1)) {
                    pass = pass + 1;
                }
                answer2 = popup.showInputDialog(Opt);
                if (answer2.equals(answerKey2)) {
                    pass = pass + 1;

                }
                answer3 = popup.showInputDialog(Opt);
                if (answer3.equals(answerKey3)) {
                    pass = pass + 1;

                }
                answer4 = popup.showInputDialog(Opt);
                if (answer4.equals(answerKey4)) {
                    pass = pass + 1;

                }
                answer5 = popup.showInputDialog(Opt);
                if (answer5.equals(answerKey5)) {
                    pass = pass + 1;

                }
                answer6 = popup.showInputDialog(Opt);
                if (answer6.equals(answerKey6)) {
                    pass = pass + 1;

                }
                answer7 = popup.showInputDialog(Opt);
                if (answer7.equals(answerKey7)) {
                    pass = pass + 1;

                }
                answer8 = popup.showInputDialog(Opt);
                if (answer8.equals(answerKey8)) {
                    pass = pass + 1;

                }
                answer9 = popup.showInputDialog(Opt);
                if (answer9.equals(answerKey9)) {
                    pass = pass + 1;

                }
                answer10 = popup.showInputDialog(Opt);
                if (answer10.equals(answerKey10)) {
                    pass = pass + 1;

                }

                if (pass >= 0 && pass < 4) {
                    score = "F";
                    failcounter++;
                } else if (pass >= 4 && pass < 6) {
                    score = "C";
                    passcounter++;
                } else if (pass >= 6 && pass < 8) {
                    score = "B";
                    passcounter++;
                } else if (pass >= 8 && pass < 11) {
                    score = "A";
                    passcounter++;
                }
                fail = 10 - pass;
                System.out.println("Student ID: " + studentIDArr[i]);
                System.out.println("Student Score: " + score);
                System.out.println("The Student passed " + pass + " questions");
                System.out.println("The Student failed " + fail + " questions");

            }
            System.out.println("Number of Students Passed: " + passcounter);
            System.out.println("Number of Students Failed: " + failcounter);
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong Number", "Error!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code here with the basic format from your IDE. Somebody else in this site can format it for you and then you will learn how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are wanting to use the `java.io.BufferedWriter` where the print lines are located.

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());         
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);     
bw.write(content);  
bw.close();
```

Comment: which line do I implement this. Java truly confuses me?

Comment: @StefanHex                                                                                                                      `File file = new File(studentIDArr[i].toString()+".txt");`                                      
`FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());`      
`BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw); `   
               
`bw.write("Student ID: " + studentIDArr[i] + "\n");`
`bw.write("Student Score: " + score+  "\n"); `      bw.write("The Student passed " + pass + " questions\n");
       bw.write("The Student failed " + fail + " questions\n");
       bw.close();`

Comment: @StefanHex did this work for you? Can you select it as the answer please :D